# PJSUA not responding with INVITE containing Authorization header when SIP server sends 401 unauthorized

Tags: pjsip, pjsua2

I'm trying to get PJSUA to run on a Raspberry Pi so I can place calls.

I'm using known good credentials for authentication. I've got all the auth data in a config file I call when opening PJSUA:

`pjsua --config-file ~/pjsua.conf`

**~/.pjsua.conf**

```
--id sip:[REDACTED NUMBER]@[REDACTED SERVER]
--registrar sip:[REDACTED SERVER]
--username [REDACTED NUMBER]@[REDACTED SERVER]
--password [REDACTED]
--realm [REDACTED SERVER]
--auto-play 
--null-audio
--play-file /home/pi/sounds/announcement.wav
--local-port 5061
```

**Auth inside PJSUA**

On load, the following is visible above the available commands, showing that it has correctly registered:

```
*[ 2] sip:[REDACTED NUMBER]@[REDACTED SERVER]: 100/In Progress (expires=0)
   Online status: Online
```

But when I go to place a call, the `INVITE` goes out correctly, is responded to by a `401 Unauthorized`, and PJSUA stops then, not responding with another `INVITE` containing an `Authorization` header.

Am I just missing a configuration option which will kick this into gear?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer by noticing one difference from my config file in comparison to the documentation.

I needed to replace my `realm` line with the following:

`--realm: *`

After that, authentication went ahead perfectly and calls were able to be placed.